# Extraer por nombre tipo String ASP NET 7 controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net

Estoy usando `asp net core 7` para crear una `API CRUD`, tengo ya desarrollados todos los métodos correspondientes, *(Create, update, delete, get, getById)*, y todo va bien pero el problema es cuando quiero extraer mis datos cuando la etapa sea una en específico y al ser mi etapa tipo `string` no me es posible extraer los datos como lo hago normalmente con en el `getById`.

**Este es el error:**

> System.ArgumentException: 'The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet.Find' was of type 'string', which does not match the property type of 'int'.

**Mi método getById(extraer por id):**

```
 [HttpGet]

 [Route("extraerId/{id_Ubi}")]

 public IActionResult ExtraerPorId(int id_Ubi)
 {
     
Ubicacion ub = _controlInventariosContext.Ubicacions.Find(id_Ubi);

     if (ub == null)
     {
         return BadRequest("producto no encontrado");
     }


     try
     {

         ub = _controlInventariosContext.Ubicacions.Include(c => c.AlmacenamientosBaks).Where(p => p.IdUbi == id_Ubi).FirstOrDefault();

         return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "OK", Response = ub });
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

         return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = ex.Message, Response = ub });
     }
 }
```

Y luego estoy intentando adaptar para extraer por una variable tipo `String`, pero aquí es donde tengo el problema.

```
[HttpGet]

 [Route("extraeretapa/{etapa?}")]

 public IActionResult ExtraerPorEtapa(string etapa)
 {

     Ubicacion ub = _controlInventariosContext.Ubicacions.Find(etapa);


     if (ub == null)
     {
         return BadRequest("producto no encontrado");
     }


     try
     {

         ub = _controlInventariosContext.Ubicacions.Include(c => c.AlmacenamientosBaks).Where(p => p.Etapa == etapa).FirstOrDefault();

         return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = "OK", Response = ub });
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

         return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new { mensaje = ex.Message, Response = ub });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta lo que contiene la clase `Ubicacion`. Por otro lado, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Saludos.